# Angular - Refactor relative Imports

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I startet coding in Angular 7 a while ago, learning it on the fly. Recently I recognized, that relative imports are not very desirable. That is why I added this to my `tsconfig.json`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@application/*": [
        "src/app/application/*"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Now I would like to refactor my imports form this:

```
import { ApplicationLogService } from './../../../service/application-log.service';
import { ApplicationLogTableComponent } from './../../tables/application-log-table/application-log-table.component';
```

to this:

```
import { ApplicationLogService } from '@application/service/application-log.service';
import { ApplicationLogTableComponent } from '@application/components/tables/application-log-table/application-log-table.component';
```

Due to the fact, that I have a whole lot of relative imports I am looking for a way to refactor these automatically. Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: Do you use VS Code? Maybe this extension can help you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport&ssr=false#overview

Comment: @Geggi632 Yes I do, but the Auto-Import extension dies not allow for refactoring existing imports.

Comment: Hm, I searched and tried a lot of extensions now but no one can change an existing one. Didn't blieved it ^^. Only possible solution I found was to replace them with regex. For example: replace ".\/(..\/)*service" to "@application/service"